# Title is not showing in the ActionBar only the logo is showing (Have tried many solutions)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

In my app, I changed some styles and the ActionBar got disappeared. I have used these lines which brought back the ActionBar and the icon :

```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

But still the title of the app is not shown by the ActionBar.

Hare is my style.XML file :

```
   <style name="Theme.Brintin" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_brintin</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Brintin</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Brintin</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Brintin</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Brintin</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Brintin</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_brintin</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_brintin</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Brintin</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Theme.Brintin.Overflow</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/Theme.Brintin.LightPurpleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:gridViewStyle">@style/Theme.Brintin.LightPurpleBackground.GridView</item>
    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Brintin.Widget</item>

</style>

<style name="Theme.Brintin.LightPurpleBackground.GridView">
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/user_grid_spacing</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Brintin.LightPurpleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">@color/light_purple_background</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Brintin.Overflow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_menu_overflow</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Brintin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_brintin</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_brintin</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_brintin</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Brintin</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Brintin.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Brintin.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#482c6f</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Brintin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_brintin</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Brintin</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Brintin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_brintin</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Brintin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_brintin</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Brintin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_brintin</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Brintin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_brintin</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_brintin</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_brintin</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Brintin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_brintin</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Brintin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_brintin</item>
</style>
```

I have also tried this line :

```
  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Main Activity");
```

But, its still not working.

Comment: where is your styles.xml located? values? values-14? what is your targetSDK from the manifest file?

Comment: The style is located in values Folder and My min SDK is 15 and Target SDK is 21